# 3.5mm audio jack not working in Debian (testing)

Tags: debian, gnome, audio

My 3.5mm sound jack suddenly stopped working. I'm not sure what I did besides restarting my computer. The HDMI audio (and video) output still work fine. Only the HDMI output appears in Gnome sound settings even though my headphones are plugged into the 3.5mm port. I also tried plugging in a pair of speakers to make sure that the headphones weren't the problem.

[image]

My kernel version:

```
Balancar# uname -a
Linux Balancar 5.8.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.8.10-1 (2020-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried three different kernel versions I happened to have installed. With 5.7.0-3 the results were the same, and with 5.8.0-1, interestingly, I can't even get the HDMI output to show up.

Accessing `alsamixer` and unmuting all the outputs doesn't work (as suggested in similar questions here). I see two sound cards here, Realtek ALC892 (the one on my motherboard) and Nvidia GPU 71 HDMI/DP (the one on my graphics card for the HDMI output), and all the sound outputs, but unmuting them or changing the volume levels doesn't make them appear in the sound settings.

Sample `pacmd` output:

```
    Balancar# pacmd list-cards
    No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

UPDATE: Running `pacmd` as user instead of root gives me some output. `list-cards` lists the two sound cards correctly where as `list-sinks` only lists the HDMI output.

`lspci` output:

```
    Balancar# lspci|grep Audio
    00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
    01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

UPDATE:

Here's some output from `dmesg` as suggested in the answer by @dirkt. I'm not sure what I'm looking for so I tried grepping for some keywords that seem relevant. I can't spot anything here that suggests a problem:

```
Balancar# dmesg|grep Audio  
[    0.185862] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
Balancar# dmesg|grep audio
[   22.873042] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   23.046498] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[   23.046573] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   23.046651] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   23.046722] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   23.046789] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   23.046852] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[   23.046915] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   23.046978] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
Balancar# dmesg|grep realtek
[   23.046498] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[   23.046573] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   23.046651] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   23.046722] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   23.046789] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   23.046852] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[   23.046915] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   23.046978] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
Balancar# dmesg|grep PCH    
[    0.246713] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
[    0.253513] pci 0000:00:1c.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[    0.253935] pci 0000:00:1d.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
[   22.799586] iTCO_wdt: Found a Intel PCH TCO device (Version=4, TCOBASE=0x0400)
[   23.094955] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input25
[   23.095081] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input26
[   23.095983] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input27
[   23.096086] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input28
[   23.097163] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input29
[   23.097264] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input30
[   23.097359] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input31
[   23.100062] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input32
```

Here's the output of `aplay` and `arecord` commands. I can't spot anything out of the ordinary:

```
Balancar# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Balancar# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC892 Alt Analog [ALC892 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, with a quick overview how sound works:

ALSA consists of kernel drivers, libraries, and tools. The kernel drivers pick up the hardware. Have a look at `dmesg` after boot to see what they do, and if there are problems.

You can list the available output devices on the ALSA level with `aplay -l` and `arecord -l`. See if your Intel HDA sound hardware is among those.

If not, something has gone wrong on the ALSA driver level, so read `dmesg` to figure out what.

If yes, many PCs switch between headphone/speakers. Yours could do that too, or not. Have a closer look at `alsamixer` or `amixer` to figure out why it doesn't switch.

Also, on most modern distros Pulseaudio is running by default. Pulseaudio is one level above ALSA, and provides sound transport between devices, programs etc. If you didn't disable it on purpose, figure out what you did (uninstall some packages?) to make it go away, and undo it.

---

Ok, the HDA card detects fine, and the headphone has the correct autoconfig info. Which means it's probably a mixer setting.

Shut down Pulseaudio again (`pulseaudio --kill`). We want to debug on the ALSA level only, to make things simpler.

Find some WAV file, try something like

```
aplay -D plughw:CARD=PCH xxx.wav
```

start `alsamixer`, select the card with `F6`, make sure to look at all settings (left/right cursor keys), and see if you need to unmute something, or switch to headphones.

If that doesn't work, try

```
amixer -D hw:0 info
```

make sure it's the ALC892 (or change the number in `hw:0`), then do

```
amixer -D hw:0 contents
```

and upload output in a pastebin etc., link to it from question, so I can have a look.

Also figure out why the last time Pulseaudio was not running

```
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

and why it's running this time.

Comment: I added the output of some of `dmesg` and and `aplay`/ `arecord`. I can't spot anything out of the ordinary there. Pulseaudio seems to be running after all, I just needed to run the pacmd command as user instead of root. `pacmd list-sinks` only lists my hdmi while `list-cards` lists both of the sound cards. So it looks like ALSA recognizes all my sound devices correctly but Pulseaudio, for some reason, doesn't.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is probably a hardware problem. I was able to play a .wav file using `aplay` after fiddling with the headphone jack a little bit. After this, I restarted pulseaudio and the "headphones" option reappeared in the gnome sound configuration and everything seems to be working again. I'm thinking maybe the audio jack is just almost broken and the computer has difficulties recognizing when something is plugged into it. Thanks anyway for the help, it helped me find the problem. My solution will be to replace the jack, or if that doesn't help, buy a cheap external sound card.